# OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: Insufficient space for shared memory file

Tags: javafx-2

How can i delete unwanted files?

OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: Insufficient space for shared memory file:
   /tmp/hsperfdata_S188063/9185
Try using the -Djava.io.tmpdir= option to select an alternate temp location.

Comment: Cleared tmp folder, this helped in resolving the issue. or if we cant clear tmp due to any dependencies, try to change the path to point other folder.